# How can I call two methods that return DeferredResult<> in parallel?

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, asynchronous, deferred

I have a Spring Boot application and legacy code with two endpoints in a controller, both of which returns DeferredResult<> of different objects and now I need to create a new endpoint which basically calls these two methods and combine their result after some filtering and thn return it.

I'm wondering is there a way to call both these methods simultaneously and then combine their results in one call, kind of like you do with Promise.all in javascript? I just don't want to make a callback hell or wait for one operation to complete before starting another. Of couse the new endpoint will also return a ReferredResult<>.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `CompletableFuture` to run 2 threads and return the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CompletableFuture` to handle the requirement to have both endpoints results before perform your processing.

`thenCombine()` could be a good help here.

Here is a guide with a good examples [here](https://medium.com/sipios/how-to-make-parallel-calls-in-java-springboot-application-and-how-to-test-them-dcc27318a0cf)

EDIT :

This implies to change the `DeferredResult` to `CompletableFuture` and use something such as :

```
 CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture =
      CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::processRequest);
```

for both of your endpoints.

Your newly create REST endpoint would combine them with `combineThen()`

Comment: Didn't know about it. Will give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Do I need to change the return type of existing endpoints as well to `CompleteableFuture` instead of `DeferredResult`? This is something I can't do to the existing endpoints.

Comment: I can't change it because it's a legacy API and it's being used internally all over the place. If I were to change the signature I would have to refactor pretty much all code inside the microservice.

Comment: Glad you made it! Please upvote it can help others :)